# Pressure gradient - derivation for air stream

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

I need help clarifying the statement made here that

$$dp = l\frac{dp}{dx}$$

$\frac{dp}{dx}$ is an infinitely small change in pressure at some point x. $dp$ is the total change in pressure between the front and back of the particle. If $\frac{dp}{dx}$ is constant $\forall x$, then it makes sense to multiply by $l$ for $dp$. But is this true if $p(x)$ is non-linear?

[image]

Comment: This derivation introduces the concept of an *infinitesimal* change in $x$, denoted $\mathrm{d}x$. Any well-behaved (i.e. 'physical') function can be approximated as linear on an infinitely small scale. The higher-order (quadratic, cubic etc.) parts of the function are dealt with using calculus; basically one must 'add up' the pressure change $\mathrm{d}p$ for each infinitesimal slice $\mathrm{d}x$. The process by which this is handled mathematically is called *integration*.

Comment: Sure - so why is it that we multiply by $l$, rather than integrate from the back to front of the particle?

Comment: $l$ here is presumably meant to denote an infinitesimal length, i.e. $l=\mathrm{d}x$; the statement only makes sense in this case, otherwise one would indeed have to carry out the integration over $l\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: (Personally, I think the notation used here is horrible; calling the length of the volume element $l$ *clearly* suggests that it has a finite size, whereas the expression is only strictly valid in the limit $l \rightarrow 0$)